# Получить значение из Promise и использовать в другой части функции

Tags: javascript, promise

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Я прочитал с десяток вроде бы похожих вопросов тут, но не понимаю, как это применить в своём случае. Есть функция, которая возвращает ближайший рабочий день по такому алгоритму:

```
function getNextWorkDay (day) { //принимаем день
    let nextDay = addDays(day, 1) //получаем следующий день, который будем проверять

    if (!isDayOff(nextDay)) { //если этот день не СБ или ВС, дальше проверяем праздничный ли он
        //(*1)
        isHoliday(nextDay).then(answer => { // isHoliday() возвращает 0 или 1, где 1 - праздничный день
            if (answer === '1') { //если день праздничный -> вызываем функцию заново, она выполнится уже со днём+1
                getNextWorkDay(nextDay)
            }
            else { // если пришло что угодно, кроме "1" (в т. ч. сервис оказался не доступен) считаем день рабочим,
                   // выходим из этой функции, попадаем к последнему (*2) return, который вернёт текущий день (nextDay)
                return
            }
        })
    }
    else { //если день СБ или ВС -> вызываем функцию заново
        getNextWorkDay(nextDay)
    }
    //если ни в одной из проверок, функция getNextWorkDay не вызвалась заново, то считаем день рабочим и возвращаем его
    //(*2)
    return nextDay 
}
```

Но функция завершается (*2) до получения ответа из блока (*1) isHoliday(nextDay).then()". Как заставить последний return (*2) дождаться завершения проверки блока (*1)?

Как в данной логике должна выглядеть реализация? Подход в том, что если день является СБ или ВС, то проверка через сторонний сервис (isHoliday(nextDay)) не производится.

И верно ли то, что раз самая глубокая по вложенности функция (f4) возвращает promise, то все функции вверх по цепочке должны возвращать promise? Иначе код в (f1) выполнится не дождавшись ответа.

```
f1(){f2()} //получаем массив дней и выводим его на экране
↑
f2(){f3()} //в цикле заполняем массив ближайших рабочих дней
↑
f3(){f4()} //находим следующий не выходной день после переданного
↑
f4() //через fetch проверяем, не выпадает ли праздник на этот день
```

Comment: либо делаете все в коллбеке, который будет вызван после завершения промиса, либо используете await для ожидания результата выполнения прямо в этой точке кода https://learn.javascript.ru/async-await но тогда вся функция должна быть асинхронной и она будет возвращать так же промис

Comment: Не могли бы вы объяснить подробнее. То есть в участке (*2) должен быть return await какой-то переменной, объявленной в начале функции и изменённой в блоке (*1), где isHoliday(nextDay).then()? 

Дело в том, если всю реализацию делать в колбэке isHoliday(nextDay).then(), то функция isHoliday() будет вызываться в любом случае. А она должна вызываться только если функция isDayOff() вернула false.

Comment: @Unicode101, для простоты, напиши функцию, представив, что в ней только синхронные функции используются. Когда она заработает. Останется добавить только async в определении и await перед функциями, которые на самом деле синхронные.

Comment: достаточно написать `await isHoliday(nextDay).then(...` он в этой точке кода подождет завершения вызова и дальше все пойдет по плану. Но вообще весь код выглядит крайне странно, переменная nextDay устанавливается в значение только в самом начале при объявлении, а последующий код ее ни как не изменяет, так что результат всегда будет  одинаков (addDays(day, 1))

Comment: @Mike, логика в том, что функция получает какой-то день и сразу увеличивает его на один, получая "завтра". Если это "завтра" прошло все проверки, то возвращается как результат. Если на каком-то этапе не прошло, то функция вызывает себя рекурсивно, увеличивает день на 1 и снова проводит проверки. Вы считаете это плохим подходом? Как лучше реализовать такой функционал?

Comment: @Mike, просто в очередной раз неверно рекурсия реализована. Не возвращается результат со следующей итерации

Comment: @Unicode101 _функция вызывает себя рекурсивно, увеличивает день на 1 и снова проводит проверки_ - и результат рекурсивного вызова никуда не сохраняется.

Comment: @Unicode101 Так и пишите `retrun getNextWorkDay(nextDay)` или `nextDay = getNextWorkDay(nextDay)` текущая функция же не заканчивается на том что вызвала себя еще раз и результат то вернет вызывающему все равно самая первая вызыванная. И кстати если делаете функцию асинхронной (что бы использовать await) то ее саму так же надо вызывать с await

Comment: Кстати в рекурсии вообще смысла не вижу, лучше бы циклом сделали бесконечным с return когда результат готов

Comment: @Mike, разве не достаточно того, что каждый раз при рекурсивном вызове, функция вызывается с новым параметром? Она вызывается до тех пор, пока не дойдёт до return и тогда этот последний переданный параметр мы получаем как результат выполнения функции

Comment: @Unicode101 Нет, как написал выше Grundy, функция то вызывается, но то что она вернула никуда не сохраняется и в первую точку вызова не возвращается. потому что при втором вызове функции у нее будет собственная переменная nextDay

Comment: У вас сейчас фактически написано `function x(n) { if(n>3) return n; x(n+1); return n;}` вот вызовете такую функцию как x(1) получите 1. А должно быть `function x(n) { if(n>3) return n; return x(n+1);}` тогда она вернет 4